# Need help for passing object to other class (scoreboard, bukkit)

Tags: java, class, object, bukkit

Since yesterday I started to make my first plugin and there appeared some issues. I have class for scoreboard. And there is methods to make scoreboard, load it and change scores.

Here it is:

```
package eu.anavicius.TomTom1997.TomTowerDefence;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.DisplaySlot;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.Objective;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.Score;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.Scoreboard;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.ScoreboardManager;

public class Votes implements Listener {

    public Scoreboard board;
    public Score scores[] = new Score[6];

    public void sBoard () {
        ScoreboardManager manager = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager();
        Scoreboard board = manager.getNewScoreboard();

        Objective obj = board.registerNewObjective("VoteMap", "dummy");
        obj.setDisplayName("Vote for maps!");
        obj.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);

        Score scores[] = new Score[6];

        for (int i = 1; i<6; i++) {
            scores[i] = obj.getScore("Map " + i);
            scores[i].setScore(0);
            this.scores[i] = scores[i];
        }
    }

    public void setScore(int i) {
        int sc = scores[i].getScore();
        scores[i].setScore(sc+=1);

        for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
            p.setScoreboard(board);
        }
    }

    public void showTo (Player player) {
        player.setScoreboard(this.board);
    }

}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to change scores or load it to the player in different classes. Example:

```
//On my main class

public class Main extends Javaplugin {
    Votes vote = new Votes();

    public void onEnable() {
        vote.sBoard();// Initialized scoreboard
    }
}

// another class

public class JoinDicsEvents {
    // what should i write here to acces my initialized
    // scoreboard (I mean write vote.showTo(player){})
    // Everytime when I try something there appears NPE
}
```

Comment: Just throwing this out there. Your `vote` reference is inside of the class Main and is not accessible from a different class such as JoinDiscsEvents in the way you show. You could pass the reference into JoinDiscsEvents if you create an instance of that class inside of the Main class.

Comment: Just use `Votes vote = new Votes(); vote.sBoard();` in any class you want to initialize the scoreboard, or, if you were to make the method `static`, you could just use `Votes.sBoard();`.

Comment: But if I need use that scoreboard in three different classes that means I have to create three scoreboards which I don't want to do. What I need to do is use **created** scoreboard

Comment: The best solution may be dependency injection, but I'm not 100% clear on your problem to fully recommend this. Where do you create JoinDicsEvents relative to your Main class?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what are you asking for, but in the same package.

Comment: Do you create a `new Main()` anywhere in your code? Do you call `new JoinDicsEvents()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: No it isn't necessary, because those classes have methods which uses bukkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: 
Change your class vote as follows 
1) Make Scoreboard and scores reference static

```
public class Votes implements Listener {

  public static Scoreboard board;
  public static Score scores[] = new Score[6];
```

2) Change your method sBoard to

```
   public static void sBoard () {
        ScoreboardManager manager = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager();
        if(board==null)
        board = manager.getNewScoreboard();

        Objective obj = board.registerNewObjective("VoteMap", "dummy");
        obj.setDisplayName("Vote for maps!");
        obj.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);

        Score scores[] = new Score[6];

        for (int i = 1; i<6; i++) {
            scores[i] = obj.getScore("Map " + i);
            scores[i].setScore(0);
            this.scores[i] = scores[i];
        }
    }
```

Now you could access the *board* from other classes using **Votes**.*board*

Comment: Sorry I'm newbie, but I don't understand why I need ScoreboadManager class? And what does the singleton do?

Comment: Singleton is when you create just one object of a class and have it shared among all,which seems to be what you need. YOu can get this done by having a static variable. YOu have imported the scoreboardManager whose source code I presumed was available to you . In case it isnt then just create a static instance of the Scoreboard in any class and access it from there.

Comment: `board=new Scoreboard();` <--- this part throws: Cannot instantiate the type Scoreboard

Comment: Thank you very much! I fixed some mistakes myself and now this class works! You're he best :)

Comment: I know, but I can't find any solutions :/.

Comment: @Hovercraft :I concur..I suggested a Singleton pattern but It seems hez using a 3rd party library and the only way to use the same would be this .Personally I'm not fond of this approach either.

Comment: Then I remove my down-vote. I must claim ignorance for use of Bukkit.